# ansibleからvagrantで立てたマシンへのpingが通らない

Tags: vagrant, ansible

ansibleの学習を始めたのですが、`ansible all -i hosts -m ping`を実行したところ下記のエラーが出て先に進めません。

```
vagrant-machine | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: connect to host 127.0.0.1 port 22: Connection refused\r\n", 
    "unreachable": true
}
```

`vagrant ssh-config`の結果は下記の通りです

```
Host default
  HostName 127.0.0.1
  User vagrant
  Port 2200
  UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
  PasswordAuthentication no
  IdentityFile /Users/user/Dev/xkxaxkx/ansible-tutorial/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key
  IdentitiesOnly yes
  LogLevel FATAL
```

またhost一覧はhostsファイルに定義し、下記のように一行で記述しています

```
vagrant-machine ansible_host=127.0.0.1 ansible-port=2200 ansible_user=vagrant ansible_ssh_private_key_file=.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key
```

カレントディレクトリにansible.cfgを配置し下記の通り記述しています

```
[defaults]
host_key_checking = False
```

特に余分な改行等は見当たりません。
解決方法についてご教示いただければと思います。

Comment: `vagrant ssh-config`の出力中、`Port 2200`と記載されていますが、`Port 22`の記載誤りですか?

Comment: @user20098 Port 2200で正しいです

Answer (score 1):

エラー内容からすると、127.0.0.1:22に接続しようとして失敗しているように見えます。

ホスト一覧の以下の記述

```
    ansible-port=2200
```

は、

```
    ansible_port=2200
```

の誤りではないでしょうか?
(ポート番号の指定がうまくいってないので、デフォルトの22番に接続しようとしているように思います)